# How to save a dataset value to a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am  trying to save my dataset changes  into  database through UpdateCommand.

I am using this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
constr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
con.ConnectionString = constr;

SqlCommand UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand();
// SqlCommand locationstock = con.CreateCommand();
SqlCommand UpdateLocationStock = con.CreateCommand();

UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update tblCurrentGameData set sales=@sales,GameStatus=@gameStatus,QOH=@qoh, SalesRatio=@sr,PeriodSalesRatio=@psr,AvgAdjustmentRatio=@avgajdr,NewForeCastQty=@newQty,totalsales=@totSales,MAForCastQty=@movingAvgQty where locationid=@locationId and stockid=@stockId and IntervalTimeId=@periodId";
////UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update tblCurrentGameData set sales=@sales,GameStatus=@gameStatus,QOH=@qoh, SalesRatio=@sr,PeriodSalesRatio=@psr,AvgAdjustmentRatio=@avgajdr,NewForeCastQty=@newQty,totalsales=@totSales,MAForCastQty=@movingAvgQty where RecordId=@rid";
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@sales", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "sales");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@gameStatus", SqlDbType.Bit, 1, "GameStatus");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@qoh", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "QOH");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@sr", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "SalesRatio");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@psr", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "PeriodSalesRatio");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@avgajdr", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "AvgAdjustmentRatio");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@newQty", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "NewForeCastQty");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@totSales", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "TotalSales");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@movingAvgQty", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "MAForCastQty");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@stockId", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "StockId");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@locationId", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "LocationId");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@periodId", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "IntervalTimeId");


UpdateLocationStock.CommandText = "update tblLocationSpecificStock set CurrentSalesAverage=@sav, SalesRatioAverage=@sravg where locationid=@locationId and stockid=@stockId ";
UpdateLocationStock.Parameters.Add("@sav", SqlDbType.Decimal, 16, "CurrentSalesAverage");
UpdateLocationStock.Parameters.Add("@sravg", SqlDbType.Decimal, 16, "SalesRatioAverage");
UpdateLocationStock.Parameters.Add("@stockId", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "StockId");
UpdateLocationStock.Parameters.Add("@locationId", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "LocationId");

da.UpdateCommand = UpdateCommand;
da.Update(gameData,"GameData");

da.UpdateCommand = UpdateLocationStock;

da.Update(gameData.Tables["LocationStockData"]);
gameData.AcceptChanges();
```

I am  having changes in my dataset 'GameData' but these changes are not saved in database.
I searched over net for the solution,but everywhere i am finding a similiar solution. I am stucked with this issue
Can someone  help me where i am going wrong?  or if having any new suggestions on how to store  my dataset into database.?

Comment: It may help if you pare this down to a minimum working (or in your case, non-working) example. You can certainly write some test code that will build a proper `DataSet` instance which you can try saving to the database.

Comment: I tried using a test code,to update some values,and it updated the databasae successfully. But the same part is not working with this piece of code.

Comment: In that case the first thing I would check is the RowState on each row in the DataSet instance you are trying to base the updates on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply changes on database you should have criteria on your command, This is very important,because I just realized, once i had this problem. and I add criteria to my query.I mean --> " update ... where id=1 " 
Preferably, Dataset likes primary key or unique key to save changes to database.
if you can, try use one primary key to update instead of composite key.